# What if a framework imports some library which the main project also imports?

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

There is no code, just a pure engineering question.

Say I'm developing an iOS App project `A`, which import a framework `B`.
Framework `B` uses some third party open-source (static) libraries, such as AFNetworking, MBProgressHUD or BlocksKit. My project `A` also imports some of the same libraries.

So my question is whether the framework `B` contains all the code binary, including the third party library?(I guess yes) And so does my project. Does that means the final App binary contains several copies of the same code (if the libraries are of the same/different version(s)) which occupy some unnecessary volume of the app?

If both framework `A` and our project `B` use Cocoapods to manage libraries, will the problem be fixed?

Another related question: what "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" option in build settings is used for?

Comment: Those are dynamic libraries aren't they?  If so there is no "contains" involved.

Comment: Why？What if static libraries？

Comment: I will add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If those third-party frameworks are dynamic libraries (`.dylib` or `.framework`) then they are only referenced from the project that use them, they are not "contained" in the project's executable (by which I mean executable or dynamic library).  The third-party dynamic library must be supplied along with the app (normally in the `Frameworks` folder).

If those third-party frameworks are static libraries (`.a` or sometimes `.framework`) then they are contained in the executable, so potentially you can have multiple copies of the library within the same app.  There is a potential linker issue here as the symbols from the third-party frameworks defined in multiple places, but by default they should be hidden so as to not cause this issue.